# Smoothy move markers on Google Map not working in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I placed car marker on google map for smoothy move to destination location. Here I can rotate the markers but it's not getting move to the destination. Can anyone identify what's code with the below code?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((self.delegate?.userLocation?.coordinate.latitude)!, (self.delegate?.userLocation?.coordinate.longitude)!)
    self.setUpDriverMarkerWithNewLocation(location: centerCoordinate)
}

func setUpDriverMarkerWithNewLocation(location : CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    self.sourceMarker.icon = UIImage(named:  "ARCar")
    let centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(13.02025636601701, 80.26621352881193)
    self.sourceMarker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0.5), y: CGFloat(0.5))
    self.sourceMarker.rotation = CLLocationDegrees(getHeadingForDirection(fromCoordinate: centerCoordinate, toCoordinate: location))
    self.sourceMarker.position = location
    self.sourceMarker.map = self.rideMapView
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setValue(Int(2.0), forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({() -> Void in
        self.sourceMarker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0.5), y: CGFloat(0.5))
        self.sourceMarker.rotation = self.rotation

    })
    self.sourceMarker.position = centerCoordinate
    //this can be new position after car moved from old position to new position with animation
    self.sourceMarker.map = self.rideMapView
    self.sourceMarker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0.5), y: CGFloat(0.5))
    self.sourceMarker.rotation = CLLocationDegrees(getHeadingForDirection(fromCoordinate: centerCoordinate, toCoordinate: location))
    CATransaction.commit()
}


func getHeadingForDirection(fromCoordinate fromLoc: CLLocationCoordinate2D, toCoordinate toLoc: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Float {

    let fLat: Float = Float((fromLoc.latitude).degreesToRadians)
    let fLng: Float = Float((fromLoc.longitude).degreesToRadians)
    let tLat: Float = Float((toLoc.latitude).degreesToRadians)
    let tLng: Float = Float((toLoc.longitude).degreesToRadians)
    let degree: Float = (atan2(sin(tLng - fLng) * cos(tLat), cos(fLat) * sin(tLat) - sin(fLat) * cos(tLat) * cos(tLng - fLng))).radiansToDegrees
    if degree >= 0 {
        return degree - 180.0
    }
    else {
        return 360 + degree - 180
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to get path between your points on map, and call sourceMarker.position for each point in path, and duration must be counted according to speed of the car

Comment: please post the answer how to do that

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik please post the answer